# I have the file name open...Now how do I actually get the file itself to open?

Tags: vba, file-io, openfiledialog

I have a code that allows me to use an open file dialog to select a file. Once selected, the file path displays in Form3. What I'm trying to do from there is click Command_Button1 (Open) and physically open the file.

I can provide codes and JPEGs...but won't cloud this up until it is necessary :) I'm not using Common Dialog so the code is somewhat lengthy.

I looked online for a few hours yesterday and the closest I got was how to get it to open an Excel file...but this isn't Excel.

P.S. I'm new to VBA...so if this isn't as simple as a few lines of code and I'm missing the difficulty of it, please let me know. It seems like it should be a simple enough process...

Edit 1:
@mehow, Do you think it could be because the whole path name isn't displaying? I double clicked Open and nothing happened like you said[image: JPEG]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already know the path then..

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    dim myPath as String
    myPath = "C:\files\file1.exe"
    Dim shell As Object
    Set shell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    shell.Open myPath
End Sub
```

Comment: It doesn't work, but it's a lot closer than where I was...thank you!!! I should be able to manipulate it from here :)

Comment: what do you mean it `doesn't work`? What does not work about it?

Comment: The button still isn't doing anything...no errors about it...I think it's just my file path. My path is being stored as a string and changes depending on what the user selects on the previous form. So instead of myPath = "C:\...." it will look more like myPath = FileName...maybe I've done it wrong. I've tried a few ways.

Comment: @meer2kat well, if you have that button on the userform then double click it. It will take you to the procedure that fires when you click the button. See answer `Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()`. Also make sure the path is valid and accessible within the `CommandButton1_click`

Comment: I sent a JPEG in the next reply...do you think this could be why?

Comment: @meer2kat yep. I am 99% sure that's the reason.

Comment: Sorry, edited that. I will try and fix that then. Thank you again for your help. I'll confirm that it worked later on.